# Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) App cookie consent value

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

ASP.NET Core offers EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) support out of the box with a cookie consent feature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential 
    // cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;

    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

A Blazor Server App can use nearly the same code and make it work:

ConsentCookie.razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

@inject IHttpContextAccessor Http
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


@if (showBanner)
{
    <div id="cookieConsent" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        Consent to set cookies.
        <button type="button" class="accept-policy close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" data-cookie-string="@cookieString" @onclick="AcceptMessage">
            Accept Cookie
        </button>
    </div>
}
@code {
    ITrackingConsentFeature consentFeature;
    bool showBanner;
    string cookieString;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        consentFeature = Http.HttpContext.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
        showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
        cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
    }

    private void AcceptMessage()
    {
        // JsInterop call to store the consent cookies.
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CookieFunction.acceptMessage", cookieString);
    }
}
```

_Host.cshtml

```
<script>
    window.CookieFunction = {
        acceptMessage: function (cookieString) {
            document.cookie = cookieString;
        }
    };    
</script>
```

MainLayout.razor

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        <ConsentCookie />

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/tips-and-tricks/how-do-i-set-consent-cookies-in-blazor

However since Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) apps run client-side the `HttpContext` features wont work. How can I add cookie consent for Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) without using any third party library like `Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.GdprConsent`?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.GdprConsent/
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18055#issuecomment-881316391
https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/vfx8h4/blazor_wasm_gdpr_and_cookie_consent/

I don't want to use Blazored LocalStorage to access local storage either.

https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it without using any third party library and storing the consent in local storage with key `CookiePolicyAccepted`.

ConsentCookie.razor

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@if (showBanner)
{
    <div id="cookieConsent" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: auto;">
        This app only uses strictly necessary cookies to function. No personal data is collected
        <button type="button" class="accept-policy close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" @onclick="AcceptMessage">
            Accept Cookies
        </button>
    </div>
}
@code {
    bool showBanner = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var cookiePolicyAccepted = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("GetCookiePolicyAccepted");
        if (cookiePolicyAccepted == false)
        {
            showBanner = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task AcceptMessage()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("SetCookiePolicyAccepted");
        showBanner = false;
    }
}
```

MainLayout.razor

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
        <ConsentCookie />
    </div>
</div>
```

MainLayout.razor.css

```
.main {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

wwwroot\index.html

```
<script>
    function SetCookiePolicyAccepted() {
        localStorage.setItem('CookiePolicyAccepted', 'true');
    }

    function GetCookiePolicyAccepted() {
        const cookiePolicy = localStorage.getItem('CookiePolicyAccepted');
        if (cookiePolicy === 'true') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is really a great post!!

I've added the possibility to withdraw the cookie in my footer Razor component, something like that:

```
<li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="javascript:void(0);" @onclick="WithdrawCookiePolicyAccepted">Google Maps Cookie Withdraw</a></li>
```

with this code behind:

```
@code {
    bool showBanner = true;
    private async Task WithdrawCookiePolicyAccepted()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("WithdrawCookiePolicyAccepted");
        showBanner = false;
    }
}
```

In my Index.html I've put this code:

```
function WithdrawCookiePolicyAccepted() {
        localStorage.removeItem('CookiePolicyAccepted');
        location.reload();
    }
```